# Difference between "constitution" and " structure"

Tags: differences

The main kind of problem which I always face in English language is my inability to find out the difference between two similar words . Now I can't really understand the difference between "constitution" and "structure". I'd be more than happy if someone guides me to get the difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First and foremost, the words ***constitution*** and ***structure*** are considered [synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/constitution).

That being said, I would use them slightly differently in my own speech and writings.  I would choose the word constitution when talking about *what* something is made of, while I would use structure to talk about *how* it was made.  This may be a difference from others, or a regional distinction.  The [definition of structure](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/structure) supports my own definition; the word structure is used to describe:

> mode of building, construction, or organization; arrangement of parts, elements, or constituents

Likewise, the two main [definitions of constitution](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/constitution) are as follows:

> 1. the way in which a thing is composed or made up; makeup; composition
> 2. the physical character of the body as to strength, health, etc.

Therefore, I would conclude that both ***constitution*** and ***structure*** can be used to describe how something is made.  *Structure* tends to refer more to the arrangement of the entities the object is composed of, while *constitution* refers to the identity of the entities themselves.

Comment: Additionally: A vigorous person has a strong constitution, but never a "strong structure".  A well-built bunker has a strong structure, but never a "strong constitution".

Comment: Agreed - basically synonyms, but structure leans more towards physical arrangement, and constitution towards the materials involved.